# MongoDB Mongoose select documents between a date range

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I've a collection called `events`. Sample document is like this.

[image]

**I want to select** documents with in date range of `'2019-01-11'` to `'2019-11-27'`.
What I've done is this. But this seems not working.
How do I achieve this using `MongoDB` `Mongoose`?

```
$match: {
                    createdAt: {
                        $gte: {
                            $dayOfYear: '2019-01-11'
                        },
                        $lte: {
                            $dayOfYear: '2019-11-27'

                        }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: have you tried `$gte` and converting the date value to `new Date(<you date>)` and pass? instead `$dayOfYear`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `Date()` object instead. I am not sure if this affects the timezone as well.

```js
  db.collection.find({
                        "createdAt": { 
                                       "$gte": new Date('2019, 1, 11'), 
                                       "$lt" : new Date(2019, 11, 27)
                                      }
                     })
```

Comment: There is a small error in your code. Either you use the quotes to generate a date object: `new Date('2019, 1, 11')` or you have keep in mind when using numbers that (only) the month is 0-based, like `new Date(2019, 10, 27)`

Comment: Thanks! Forgot about that.